# Split and save in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SavePost]
    @PostTitle NVARCHAR(max),
    @PostDescription NVARCHAR(max),
    @PostDate DATETIME,
    @Author NVARCHAR(100),
    @Tag NVARCHAR(250), --it bring c#,asp.net,mvc
    @Category NVARCHAR(250)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[ForumPost](PostTitle, PostDescription, PostDate,
                                 Author, Tag, Category)
   VALUES(@PostTitle, @PostDescription, @PostDate,
          @Author, @Tag, @Category)
END
```

Table `[dbo].[ForumPost]` has `postid` which is auto increment. There is another tables called `Tag`. In a same procedure I want to insert a value into `Tag` table which has column `postid` and `tag`. But unable to insert a value in `tag` table. Means if `postid=2` I want a result like this.

Table **tag**

```
postid | tag
------------
2      | c#
2      | asp.net
2      |  mvc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the latest inserted identity value and then use it in your second insert:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SavePost]
  .....
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[ForumPost](PostTitle, PostDescription, PostDate,
                                 Author, Tag, Category)
   VALUES(@PostTitle, @PostDescription, @PostDate,
          @Author, @Tag, @Category)

   -- declare variable to hold newly inserted IDENTITY value
   DECLARE @NewPostID INT

   -- fetch the newly inserted IDENTITY value
   SELECT @NewPostID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

   -- use that value in the next INSERT into the "Tag" table
   INSERT INTO dbo.Tag(PostId, ......)
   VALUES(@NewPostID, .......)
END
```

As a side-note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. That's a prefix that Microsoft has reserved for its own use. There is a risk this will not work properly, or that it might cause slowdowns. I would **avoid** the `sp_` prefix - use something like `proc_` or no prefix that all...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I get post id through `SCOPE_IDENTITY()
` but how can I split data `c#,asp.net,mvc` and insert into `Tag ` table.

Comment: @ShreeKhanal: there are **THOUSANDS** of posts on this - just Google or Bing for it! Or see [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql) with several useful links....